# Pydantic init/validating model from dict is changing sub model to None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I have a pydantic model like below:

```
class ServiceOrderModel(BaseModel):
    service_order_id: int | None = None
    service_order_number: str | None = None
    service_order_items: Optional[List[ServiceOrderItemModel]] = Field(
        None, alias="service_order_item"
    )

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True
```

I am trying to initialize this model from a dictionary:

```
service_order_model = ServiceOrderModel(**service_order_dict)
```

In my service_order_dict I clearly have an item of "service_order_items" which is not empty and is a list of dicts which fit the model of ServiceOrderItemModel.

Right after I initialize service_order_model and check it, it sets service_order_items to None... Has anyone ran into this?

I am trying to use sqlalchemy to insert this nested object into an oracle database.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal definition of the `service_order_dict` to the code, such that the issue becomes reproducible?